# Hypothesis testing convention

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

In a test for the difference of two means.

Null Hypothesis: $\bar{x}_1 = \bar{x}_2$
Alternative Hypothesis:   $\bar{x}_1 < \bar{x}_2$
After the data is collected, I find that $\bar{x}_1$ is much greater than $\bar{x}_2$.
Should I perform a statistical test. If so, then what?
Alternatively, do I conclude that I assumed the wrong direction for the effect?

Comment: Hypotheses should be about population parameters/processes not sample quantities. Clearly $\bar{x}_1 = \bar{x}_2$ is not true, you know their values, just look at the numbers (well, unless by chance that did come out to be equal, but again, you just look at the numbers). Whether you wish to perform a test is up to you. If you mean "they're obviously very different and the formal test will be a foregone conclusion", you can't tell that from the sample means alone.

Comment: I believe that the predicted effect must be specified before collecting the data. Then the the question is what to do with the surprise test statistics.

Comment: From a practical viewpoint, in this type of situation I do run the test I had originally planned and write up the results saying that the comparison was significant, but to the direction opposite of what was hypothesized.

Answer (score 0):

This is why you should not use one sided tests unless you are really sure, or else don't care about the other direction.

You can, strictly, only do a test of something you know won't work and can, then, only fail to reject the null hypothesis.